# Class 'Application' is not abstract and does not implement abstract member public abstract fun registerWith(p0: PluginRegistry):

Tags: android, ios, flutter, kotlin, firebase-cloud-messaging

When I am running my flutter project on my macbook for ios it's running properly but getting an error for android and showing this error as I mentioned below:

**e: /Users/satyamtripathi/Desktop/ChatApp/android/app/src/main/kotlin/com/example/myapp/Application.kt: (12, 1): Class 'Application' is not abstract and does not implement abstract member public abstract fun registerWith(p0: PluginRegistry): Unit defined in io.flutter.plugin.common.PluginRegistry.PluginRegistrantCallback**

**e:/Users/satyamtripathi/Desktop/ChatApp/android/app/src/main/kotlin/com/example/myapp/Application.kt: (18, 5): 'registerWith' overrides nothing**

**Application.kt**

```
package com.example.myapp



import io.flutter.app.FlutterApplication;

import io.flutter.plugin.common.PluginRegistry;

import io.flutter.plugin.common.PluginRegistry.PluginRegistrantCallback;

import io.flutter.plugins.GeneratedPluginRegistrant;

import io.flutter.plugins.firebasemessaging.FlutterFirebaseMessagingService;


class Application : FlutterApplication(), PluginRegistrantCallback {

    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
        FlutterFirebaseMessagingService.setPluginRegistrant(this)
    }
    override fun registerWith(registry: PluginRegistry?) {
        io.flutter.plugins.firebasemessaging.FirebaseMessagingPlugin.registerWith(registry?.registrarFor("io.flutter.plugins.firebasemessaging.FirebaseMessagingPlugin"));
    }
}
```

**MainActivity.kt**

```
package com.example.myapp


import androidx.annotation.NonNull

import io.flutter.plugins.GeneratedPluginRegistrant

import io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterActivity

import io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterEngine


class MainActivity : FlutterActivity()
{

    override fun configureFlutterEngine(@NonNull flutterEngine: FlutterEngine) {
        GeneratedPluginRegistrant.registerWith(flutterEngine);

    }
}
```

Comment: Please edit your question and place code in code blocks, and also separate content and code, see how do I ask a good question [ask].

Comment: Did you ever get an answer to this issue?

Comment: Can u make a flutter doctor? i have the same issue after upgrading to • Flutter version 3.0.0 & Android SDK version 32.1.0-rc1

Answer (score 18):

I changed

```
override fun registerWith(registry: PluginRegistry?)
```

to this

```
override fun registerWith(registry: PluginRegistry),
```

Comment: you're such a life saver, it worked. thanks