# Flutter 3.0.2: Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugKotlin'

Tags: android, flutter

I'm upgrading Flutter to 3.0.2 and android has this issue when running on the emulator.
I'm searching for the same issue and updating kotlin_version to lastest but it's not working.
I'm also clean and pub get but still not working.
anyone has a solution.

ext.kotlin_version = '1.5.10'

Flutter doctor:

```
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.0.2, on macOS 12.4 21F79 darwin-arm, locale en-VN)
    • Flutter version 3.0.2 at /Users/anhdinhhoangquang/flutter
    • Upstream repository https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
    • Framework revision cd41fdd495 (2 weeks ago), 2022-06-08 09:52:13 -0700
    • Engine revision f15f824b57
    • Dart version 2.17.3
    • DevTools version 2.12.2

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 32.1.0-rc1)
    • Android SDK at /Users/anhdinhhoangquang/Library/Android/sdk
    • Platform android-32, build-tools 32.1.0-rc1
    • Java binary at: /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/Contents/Home/bin/java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.12+0-b1504.28-7817840)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 13.3.1)
    • Xcode at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
    • CocoaPods version 1.11.3

[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
    • Chrome at /Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome

[✓] Android Studio (version 2021.2)
    • Android Studio at /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents
    • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
    • Dart plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.12+0-b1504.28-7817840)

[✓] IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition (version 2022.1)
    • IntelliJ at /Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app
    • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
    • Dart plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart

[✓] VS Code (version 1.65.2)
    • VS Code at /Users/anhdinhhoangquang/Downloads/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents
    • Flutter extension version 3.40.0

[✓] Connected device (5 available)
    • sdk gphone64 arm64 (mobile) • emulator-5554                            • android-arm64  • Android 12 (API 32) (emulator)
    • iPad của Kha (mobile)       • 647828f7a35c6397e6a75001cf0ef213d0fbdee1 • ios            • iOS 12.2 16E227
    • iPhone 13 Pro (mobile)      • F7F65BF2-C9A8-4D8C-8DB7-A0D6AAE3F811     • ios            • com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimRuntime.iOS-15-4
      (simulator)
    • macOS (desktop)             • macos                                    • darwin-arm64   • macOS 12.4 21F79 darwin-arm
    • Chrome (web)                • chrome                                   • web-javascript • Google Chrome 102.0.5005.115

[✓] HTTP Host Availability
    • All required HTTP hosts are available

• No issues found!
```

output:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugKotlin'.
> Compilation error. See log for more details

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
```

Comment: Please share error as well. So, can check.

Comment: I'm found the same issue:
https://stackoverflow.com/q/71922054/17837640

and solution:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/72485221/17837640